# Copy command in Snowflake failed to parse \n in data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-format

I have a CSV file format data that brings string values and JSON entries. For example -

| message_id | status | user_detail | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a123bxe | Success | {user_name:'jim',full_name:'Jim Mathews'} | 2021-07-28 |
| b245apl | Success | {user_name: '\n153674@dewbbe',full_name:'Dev Webbe'} | 2021-07-28 |

The file has | as field delimiter \n as a record delimiter. Because of \n coming in the data value, snowflake considers the rest as a new record and tries to enter the rest of the data under the table which eventually giving an error due to data type mismatch.

Here is the file format, I'm using:-

FILE_FORMAT =  COMPRESSION = ‘AUTO’

FIELD_DELIMITER = ‘|’

RECORD_DELIMITER = ‘\n’

SKIP_HEADER = 0

ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD='\n'

VALIDATE_UTF8 = TRUE

EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE

TRIM_SPACE = TRUE

ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = FALSE

NULL_IF = (‘NULL’, ‘null’,‘None’,‘NONE’,"""")

How should I escape the \n coming as a part of data value?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY parameter with a single quote